# Cant get Request.Querystring to pass a variable in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to pass a value (within a url) to a vbscript, that in turn, will use it to launch an executable file (at the client side, this is why im using vbscript) with that value as a parameter for that executable. e.g:

the syntax for launching this exe is

```
\\HQFileServer\Share Launch.exe 1 computername \\ServerName
```

so im passing the computername as "Name":

```
http://localhost/launchclient.asp?Name=Laptop1
```

`launchclient.asp` contains:

```
<script language="vbScript">
set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Name = Request.QueryString("Name")
oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe " & Name & " \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True
</script>
```

I tried to debug it, by removing one line at a time, when I realized that, for some reason, it seams that querystring is not passing into the script..
when I omit the `Request.QueryString("Name")` and just type in a value - it works...

any ideas why?

I have tried to search for an answer, and cant get this figured out...

Comment: Try `<script language="VBScript" runat="server">` think at the moment the code is being interpreted as client-side script not server-side in fact just replace the `<script>` tags with `<%` at the start and `%>` at the end that way the server knows that ASP should process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Right think I understand what you want to do now after reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516265/cant-get-request-querystring-to-pass-a-variable-in-vbscript#comment54822164_33519891).

To pass server-side values to client-side code blocks just use a ASP code block inside the client-side one something like this;

```
<script language="vbScript">
set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe ""<%= Request.QueryString("Name") %>"" \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True
</script>
```

This way the ASP engine will replace `<%= Request.QueryString("Name") %>` before the code block is sent to the client and will look like this;

```
<script language="vbScript">
set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe "Laptop1" \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True
</script>
```

*Also [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516265/cant-get-request-querystring-to-pass-a-variable-in-vbscript#comment54822972_33519891) you need it to be seen as a `string` value but because VBScript uses quotes (`"`) to denote strings, string within strings have to be escaped, you do this by doubling the quotes (`""`)*.

---

*Old Answer but still relevant-ish*

The code is not being processed by Classic ASP because at the moment it is classed as a client-side (HTML) script block being ignored and just passed "as is" in the server response.

There are two ways to remedy this:

1. Change the script tag so it knows it should be processed by the server by adding the `runat="Server"` attribute to the `script` tag.

   ```
   <script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
   set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Name = Request.QueryString("Name")
   oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe " & Name & " \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True
   </script>
   ```
2. Use an ASP code block.

   ```
   <%
   set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Name = Request.QueryString("Name")
   oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe " & Name & " \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True
   %>
   ```

to avoid confusion with client-side script tags I personally recommend use of the ASP code block syntax *(`<% %>`)*.

---

#### Useful Links

- [@AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17516/anthonywjones) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449277/692942) to [what's the difference between `<% %>` and `<script language=“vbscript” runat=“server”>` in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447822/692942)

Comment: Thanks for the response :). I have tested the <% %> code block, but ended up with the Launch.exe being running at the server and not at the client..

Comment: @FunkyFish Now I'm lost, what are you trying to accomplish? I did say in the answer that the code will be processed by the server, if you don't want that remove the `runat="server"`, remove `<% %>` etc. Sounds like to me you are trying to mix the two.

Comment: @FunkyFish Right think I get what you are trying to do. If you want the `launch.exe` to run at the client but pass server-side code just use a ASP code block like so `oWshShell.run "\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe <%= Request.QueryString("name") %> \\SCCM2012WAN",1,True`

Comment: In the mean time - I managed to pass a value using: '<script type="text/vbscript">
oWshShell.run("\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe " & <%=Request("Name")%> & " \\SCCM2012WAN")' --- BUT: it only passes as int where my value is a string. I have tried declaring my value as a string, but couldn't make it work (maybe sytax error?)

Comment: @FunkyFish Yeah I've already come to that conclusion and updated my answer. Also because it's VBScript quotes have to be escaped so `"` becomes `""` see my updated answer.

Comment: you got it straight on :) pro!, check out my latest comment.. the name is actually an alpha-numeric value, and the request.querystring passes it as an INT.. I Have tried to: `Dim Name As String` and than `Name = <%=Request("Name")%>` and for the run: `oWshShell.run("\\HQFileServer\Share\Launch.exe " & Name & " \\SCCM2012WAN")` and yet, still, it only passes as an INT

Comment: Lankymart - SHARP!! it worked :) thank you so much!!