# How to access div on server using classic asp vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm in the unfortunate position to work on an old legacy application written in classic asp.  To enable testing I created a mocking framework that outputs content into a hidden div.  I like to get the content of that div to evaluate it but how do I access it from server side vbscript? I looked through various posts about this but couldn't find any example except for ASP.Net, which didn't work for me.

```
class PageMock
    private PageMockArea
    ...

    public property Get PageContent
        Set PageContent = PageMockArea
    end property

    public function ExecutePageMock()
        Response.Write "<div id='PageMockArea' class='PageMock' runat='server' visibility:hidden'>"

        ...

        Call contentBuilder.BuildContentFromTemplate(aspPage, param1)

        Response.Write "</div>"
        set ExecutePageMock = contentBuilder.Delegator
    end function
end class
```

When BuildContentFromTemplate executes, I need to read the content of this div with the id="PageMockArea".  However, PageMockArea is empty when this runs,  what do I miss here?  I can see the content being generated and access it with JQuery using $('PageMockArea'), but how can I access the content on the server?

Comment: `"PageMockArea is empty when this runs"` - Where are you putting anything in it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Inside the div the content will be written to. With JQuery I would use $('PageMockArea') to get the content. But since I need it on the server side, I read that using "Runat=Server" would give me access to the content on the server, but I can't find any example on how to actually retrieve the content.

Comment: `runat="server"` is ASP.NET, this is ASP Classic.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  "I need it on the server side" isn't really clear.  If you have information you're writing to the page, that information is already server-side when you write it.  If that information is generated client-side, you'd send it to the server in another request (such as a form post or AJAX request).

Comment: The mocking framework is a generic way to run classes and collect the output of them within the PageMockArea div.  The classes will go out to the database (which is mocked) and perform transactions. The output is normally written as a web page but are redirected into this hidden div instead. What I need is now to verify that the output meets expectations and therefore need to be able to read the contents of this div on the server side .

Comment: Is this happening inside of a web browser?  Or some other application host?  It's not really clear to me what the structure of this is.

Comment: Yes, it's in a web browser. As I said, I have a div on the client side and I want to read the content on the server side so I can evaluate it.

Comment: What's *writing* the contents to the `div`?  If it's server-side code, then you already have the contents server-side.  If it's client-side code, you'd post that data back to the server.

Comment: I updated the questions with more code, hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: It sounds like whatever `contentBuilder.BuildContentFromTemplate()` is doing, that's where the data you want would be found.  If it's writing directly to `Response`, then these tests would either need to mock the `Response` or in some way validate the response buffer being sent to the client.  As you can imagine, there are limitations to what's been done with ASP Classic.  Part of me still suspects that, since this is going to a browser, this may involve posting data back to the server.

Comment: @David - `runat=server` is also classic ASP: e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447822/whats-the-difference-between-and-script-language-vbscript-runat-serve

Comment: Your server-side Classic ASP knows nothing about your div - as far as your ASP code is concerned that's just a text string you put into the Response buffer, it's not an object which can be accessed via it's id attribute.

Comment: To get the server to grab any text from the website that text will need to be in a form control and the form will need to be posted back to the server. Another way is to use javascript to grab the div contents and then post it back to an asp script via ajax.

Comment: what to you mean by "read the content"? for what? with what? why not "reading" it at the time you write it in the div?